# Can anybody explain the Logic behind the min([1,2,3,5,6], key=lambda x: abs(x-8))

Tags: python

This is my list: `a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14]`.

I want to get the number that is closest to `5`, this is the solution:

```
b = min(a, key = lambda x: abs(x-5))
```

Please explain what is happening in the above line.

Comment: `abs(x-5)` returns the distance between `x` and 5. For example, the distance between 7 and 5 is 2. Hence `|5-7| = |7-5| = 2`. The function `abs` computes the absolute value of the expression it gets. So the `min` function gives you the min over `a`, such that its absolute value from `5` is minimized

Comment: You are getting the number that is `min` w.r.t. the `abs` distance to 5.

Comment: Is the list *ordered*?

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem , Yes ,it is in asending order.

Comment: @tobias_k., after that what is the logic behind the lambda function in min() function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `abs(x-5)`

   `abs` is absolute mathematics function which is equivalent to `|x-5|`.
   example : `abs(x-5)` when `x=6` is `1`, and when `x=4` is also `1`.
2. `lambda x: abs(x-5)`

   It can be written as

   ```
   def func(x):
       return abs(x-5)
   ```

   which means for `a = [1,3,4,7,8,9,12,13,14]`

   ```
   lambda x: abs(x-5)
   ```

   will give

   ```
   [4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
   ```

3. `key = lambda x: abs(x-5)`

   Here the value returned by this lambda function is stored in `key` variable.
   Thus

   ```
   key = [4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
   ```
4. Lastly `min(a, key)`

   The `min` function uses `key` as an iterable to calculate minimum value.
   Using the position of minimum value obtained from key it displays the value from iterable a.

   Thus for

   ```
   key = [4(0), 2(1), 1(2), 2(3), 3(4), 4(5), 7(6), 8(7), 9(8)]
   ```

   minimum value is 1 at position 2 and it displays value at 2 position from iterable a

   ```
   [1(0), 3(1), 4(2), 7(3), 8(4), 9(5), 12(6), 13(7), 14(8)]
   ```

   which is 4.

Comment: Thank you  man , Thank you very much for your valuable  explanation, That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The code is using the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) builtin function, but with a `key` parameter. Thus, it does not return the *actual* minimum element of the list, but the element for which *that key function* is minimal, i.e. it behaves more like ["arg-min"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max#Arg_min) than actually "min".

In the `key` function (defined as a `lambda` expression), [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) is just the absolute difference, in this case between the parameter `x` (a number from the list) and `5`.

That line is somewhat equivalent to, but much shorter and more readable than, this loop:

```
a = [1,3,4,7,8,9,12,13,14]
b = min_k = None
for x in a:
    k = abs(x-5)
    if min_k is None or k < min_k:
        b, min_k = x, k
```

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

`min(iterable, key)` returns the *smallest* item in the `iterable` with respect to the `key`. So it iterates over the `iterable`, each time evaluates the `key(x)` for an element `x`, and then returns the element for which `key(x)` was the smallest.

Since `key=lambda x=abs(x-5)`, we thus evaluate the absolute difference between `5`, so if `x=3`, then `abs(x-5)` is `2`, etc. So this will result in the number that is the closest to `5`.

## Making this an *O(log n)* algorithm

Given the list is *ordered*, you can find this in *logarithmic* time with:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def closest(ordered_list, x):
    idx = bisect_left(ordered_list, x)
    return min(ordered_list[max(idx-1,0):idx+1], key=lambda y: abs(y-x))
```

For example:

```
>>> closest(a, -1)
1
>>> closest(a, 0)
1
>>> closest(a, 1)
1
>>> closest(a, 2)
1
>>> closest(a, 3)
3
>>> closest(a, 4)
4
>>> closest(a, 5)
4
>>> closest(a, 6)
7
>>> closest(a, 11)
12
>>> closest(a, 15)
14
```

Comment: True, but actually OP asked for explantion of the given code, not how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import numpy as np
def return_closest(a, num):

    m1 = a[np.searchsorted(a, num)]
    m2 = a[np.searchsorted(a, num)-1]
    return m2 if abs(num-m1)>abs(num-m2) else m1

a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14]
return_closest(a, 5)
```

gives 4

the function `np.searchsorted` will give you index of the upper limit (7)